# Java Regular Expression to find CSS import in HTML file

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm working on building a Java program that will download a copy of a website to a local machine while maintaining the original file hierarchy.

I'm using the following:
To find CSS of form http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp (note working)

```
private static final String HTML_CSS_TAG_PATTERN = "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
private static final String CSS_TAG_PATTERN = "(?i)<link([^>]+)>(.+?)>";
```

To find images (working fine):

```
private static final String HTML_IMG_TAG_PATTERN = "\\s*(?i)src\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
private static final String IMG_TAG_PATTERN = "(?i)<img([^>]+)>(.+?)>";
```

To find links of form http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp (working fine)

```
private static final String HTML_A_HREF_TAG_PATTERN = "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))";
private static final String HTML_A_TAG_PATTERN = "(?i)<a([^>]+)>(.+?)</a>";
```

The link and images are working fine, but the CSS file isn't. I would like it to extract the link to the CSS file so that I can save it. Could anyone help me with what I missed?

Comment: What's wrong with just using a HTML parser like http://jsoup.org? Why trying it the overcomplicated and error prone way?

Comment: It's an assignment, I have to use regexs

Answer (score 1):

Try:
CSS_TAG_PATTERN

```
<link[^>]+?text/css[^>]*?>
```

will match

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=0eb8b68aff29">
```

Comment: It's throwing the following error: 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
 at CSSRegEx.grabHTMLLinks(CSSRegEx.java:42)
 at HTML.main(HTML.java:63)


I think that means that it's finding the reference to the CSS, but there is still a mistake in CSS_TAG_PATTERN?

Comment: what is expected in group 1?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you only get CSS stylesheets try following CSS_TAG_PATTERN:

```
<link.*\s+rel="stylesheet"([^>]+)>
```

This pattern will match the following two

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="theme.css">
```

but not

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="license"  href="someStuff">
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
<link[.]+?text/css[.]*?>
```

It will match

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="theme.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="license"  href="someStuff">
```